# Нужно чтобы Google , Yandex и другие поисковые системы проиндексировали список, количеством 4 миллиона, как лучше всего это сделать?

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы

Есть список нужно чтобы поисковые системы проиндексировали его,  нужно чтобы  каждая страница этого списка была проиндексировано, как лучше всего это сделать ?

Думаю  использовать мелкий шрифт и на каждой странице поставить около 4000 названий и того будет 1000 страниц.

Есть другой способ использовать вместо страниц PDF или XLS документы так как замечал что эти документы индексируются досконально, от начало до конца.

Как лучше всего сделать ?

Если есть ссылки на эту тему буду рад посмотреть.

Comment: сделать "sitemap.xml"?

Comment: А  способ использовать мелкий шрифт  и множество страниц подходит конечно с последующей генерацией sitemap.xml ?

Comment: а зачем генерировать эту страницу с мелким шрифтом? достаточно только sitemap.xml

Comment: И зачем собственно мелкий шрифт, если она только для поискового бота, то он машина, ему все равно какой размер букв.

Comment: видимо где то написано, что в коде ботов есть строки `if (url.font.size < 5) {add_link_to_our_database_with_high_priority(url);}`

Comment: Ладно если не использовать страницы и линки на сайте, будут ли поисковые системы работать хорошо  на основе только sitemap.xml то есть   будет ли индексирован весь список  и  не забанят ли сайт за отсутствие  ликнов ?

Comment: список с sitemap будет взят на вооружение. Он собственно для этого и создан. Но только этот файл должен содержать ссылки внутри Вашего сайта. Или у Вас ссылки на внешние сайты, которые не имеют отношения к нему?

Comment: Все  ссылки внутренние ,   если сгенерировать sitemap.xml    ссылки для каждого отдельного элемента то sitemap.xml будет очень большим   4 миллиона ссылок,
Вопрос был именно в этом как лучше всего структурировать страницы  
сколько  элементов в каждом какой  размер шрифта  чтобы поисковики не забаняли ,  нужно ли использовать  PDF  ,  xml    документы ?